# Reading a raw image file with C++

Tags: c++, image

I have two identical C++ codes which each read in identical .raw image files as such:

```
this->file_variable = fopen(filename, "r")
```

They process the information within them as such:

```
status = fread ((void *)this->img1,
  sizeof(float),
  (this->width * this->height),
  this->file_variable)
)
```

The only difference between the two codes is that they were compiled on different boxes, but I'm getting completely different results from the img1 array.  I have absolutely no idea how to even start debugging this.  Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Edit: I'm slowly gaining more information on the files.  They are (width x height) 1800 x 1728 pixels, 1 channel, 8 bits depth.

Comment: Start by posting both the codes...

Comment: Can you define "completely different results"?

Comment: `float` is not necessarily the same size on each machine. They may not even represent a floating point number in the same binary format.

Comment: Mellowcandle: It's not my code (I'm just trying to fix it), so I can't post the whole thing.
Mats: When I print out the first array element, the working version gives me 0.000239 whereas the broken version gives me 3.95005e-27.
user315052: sizeof(float) gives me the same value for both codes.

Comment: unless you're using templates or you have variables with the same names in current scope, it's not necessary to use `this->`. Perhaps you could disclose a bit more of the code surrounding what you already gave?

Comment: You should at least know the format in which your RAW image is saved. You know... how many channels, how many bits per channel, the dimensions of the file and stuff like that. Do you want to read a raw image or just raw data?

Comment: didierc: I really don't think I'm allowed to post more.  I realize that makes it difficult to help, so I appreciate everyone trying. ddriver: To be honest, I really don't know anything about the files.  They're old and don't belong to me.  I have the feeling that transferring them from a Sun box to a linux box may have been the issue though.

Comment: ddriver: From what I can tell, it looks like I want to read raw data, not the image, because I'm only going to be outputting information rather than images.

Comment: What are the 'different boxes'? Are they the same 'endianness'?

Comment: Steve: The original box is SunOS sparc (big endian) and the new box is linux x86_64 (little endian).  I don't know if that was taken into account when the files were transferred.  I'm new at using binary files, so is there a way to check for this and to do the conversion if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see your problem. Your data is stored in big endian and you're reading it on a little endian system. You need to simply convert each float by reversing the byte order. Use a function like this (taken from a similar answer elsewhere):

```
float ReverseFloat( const float inFloat )
{
float retVal;
char *floatToConvert = ( char* ) & inFloat;
char *returnFloat = ( char* ) & retVal;

// swap the bytes into a temporary buffer
returnFloat[0] = floatToConvert[3];
returnFloat[1] = floatToConvert[2];
returnFloat[2] = floatToConvert[1];
returnFloat[3] = floatToConvert[0];

return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the file was written in binary format, so you need to open it likewise:

```
this->file_variable = fopen(filename, "rb")
```

Without the "b", it's being read as ASCII.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but unfortunately it doesn't change the results at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the binary (!) format of values are the same on different machines. Where do the other `this->` values come from?

Comment: All three other this-> values are hardcoded.
this->width = 360 ;
this->height = 180 ;

Answer (score 0):

Here Is A Great Function To Flip The Byte Order Of Any Variable, Which Can Be Easily Used To Change The Endianness.

```
void byteFlip(void* original, size_t numberOfBytes)
{
    char* reversed = (char*) malloc(numberOfBytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBytes; i++)
    {
        reversed[i] = ((char*)original)[numberOfBytes - i - 1];
    }
    memcpy(original, reversed, numberOfBytes);
    free(reversed);
}
```

This Will Flip The Byte Order Of The Variable Used In The 'original' parameter.
Example:

```
short a = 512;
//AAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB - 00000010 00000000
cout << a << endl; //outputs 512
byteFlip(&a, sizeof(short)); //flip byte order of 'a'
//BBBBBBBB AAAAAAAA - 00000000 00000010
cout << a << endl; //outputs 2
```

Explanation:
this function takes a pointer to any type of variable, and the size in bytes of that variable. Since we are reversing the byte order, and 1 character = 1 byte, we can therefore treat this the same way as we would reverse a string. We create a new string the same size as our variable to hold the reversed data. Now we use a for loop to copy each byte as a char in reversed order into the reversed character array variable. Once the loop has completed we can copy the memory of our reversed string into the original pointer. Finally we free the memory of the reversed string variable since it has been copied into the original pointer, and therefore no longer needed.